# How strong is "ZFC is 'very consistent'"?

Tags: logic, set-theory, incompleteness

Suppose we add a predicate "$x$ is very consistent" to $\textsf{ZFC}$, and we add the following axioms:

1. $\textsf{ZFC}$ is very consistent
2. If some theory $T$ is very consistent, then it is consistent
3. If some theory $T$ is very consistent, then $T + T\text{ is consistent}$ is also very consistent
4. Given a set $\mathcal{T}$ of very consistent theories, $\textsf{ZFC} + (\forall T \in \mathcal{T}. T \text{ is consistent})$ is very consistent

How strong is this theory? Is there some large cardinal axiom which proves its consistency?

Comment: There are issues with expressing Axioms 3 and 4. For Axiom 3, you need a definable function which takes in an arbitrary theory T and returns the theory T + 'T is consistent'. First, you should assume that T contains enough arithmetic or set theory so that 'is consistent' is expressible uniformly in the language of T. Second, you need some way to specify T in a single sentence, so T can't be too complicated. The most common choice is to restrict to r.e. theories T. The same comment applies to specifying the set of theories in Axiom 4.

Comment: If formalized correctly (according to Alex's suggestions), i guess it is still much weaker than "there is a transitive model of ZFC". So not very strong.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick argument that any reasonable way of making your notion precise gets something no stronger (and I suspect vastly weaker) than the theory $T=$ $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "There is a worldly cardinal."

Within $T$, we'll interpret "very consistent" as "has a transitive model." Conditions 1-3 are trivial (once we restrict condition 3 to theories extending $\mathsf{ZFC}$, say, to address the issue Alex Kruckman pointed out); in particular, note that every transitive model is an $\omega$-model and so does not believe false inconsistency statements.

For 4, letting $\kappa$ be the smallest inaccessible cardinal note (reasoning within $T$) that $V_\kappa$ is itself a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ which correctly sees transitive models of all set theories which have transitive models: if $A$ is a transitive model of set theory, then by downward Lowenheim-Skolem + Mostowski collapse $A$ has a countable transitive model, and any such model is a fortiori an element of $V_\kappa$.

Comment: I think you can get in a similar method that "ZFC is very consistent" is not stronger than "every set is a member of transitive model of ZFC", which is strictly weaker than the existence of worldly cardinal (and than "Ord is worldly"). (btw, in the last paragraph you used $κ$ being inaccessible, did you meant worldly?)